# How to share a SQL DataBase over the internet?

Tags: router, database-administration

[image]

According to the above figure how can I share a database over the internet that is hosted on a server and allow a remote PC to connect using its static IP and using a connection string.

Comment: You never want to make your database server directly accessible over the public Internet. Ever.

Answer (score 2):

Use a VPN tunnel to connect your remote PC to your main network. You don't have to worry about exposing your SQL server to the internet that way.

If you have multiple PCs at the remote site, you might want to use your router hardware to establish a VPN tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the port used by the client and forward that traffic through the router to the database server. Ensure that the firewall rule ***only*** allows traffic from the client's IP address. You're still potentially at risk if the client PC becomes infected with a virus and that virus is intelligent enough to monitor specific traffic and use that information to its advantage.

If at all possible have the data stream that is flowing through the firewall inspected for acceptable traffic types and patterns.

We cannot give you specific information concerning how to make those rules because we do not know the model of firewall/router that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The best, but probably too costly, solution in this case would be to have a terminal server (windows ts and citrix) in an extranet on your network and allow the remote user to connect to the Terminal Server and run SQL Server Studio or whatever application is required.
SQL Server connections over the internet should be avoiced.